# 396: error: (-5) This LBPH model is not computed yet. Did you call the train method? in function cv::face::LBPH::predict

Tags: python, opencv3.0, face-recognition

I am trying to build a face recognition program using Python 2.7.13 and OpenCV 3.3.0.

However, I receive this error when it tries to detect my face:

```
File "C:\GitProject\face_recognition\detector.py", line 20, in
 <module> Id = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])
error: C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv_contrib\modules\face\src\lbph_faces.cpp:396: 
error: (-5) This LBPH model is not computed yet. Did you call the train method? in function cv::face::LBPH::predict
```

Here is my code:

```
import cv2 ,os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import pickle

recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
recognizer.read('trainer/training_data.yml')
cascadePath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascadePath);


cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
while True:
    ret, im =cam.read()
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces=faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.2,5)
    for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(im,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(225,0,0),2)
        Id = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])
        if(conf<50):
            if(Id==1):
                Id="Anirban"
            elif(Id==2):
                Id="Sam"
        else:
            Id="Unknown"
        cv2.PutText(cv2.fromarray(im),str(Id), (x,y+h),font, 255)
    cv2.imshow('im',im) 
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF==ord('q'):
        break

cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 10):

Open your trainer, change the recognizer.save to recognizer.write. Don't forget to run the trainer again. It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused when loading the pre-trained .yml file. Even though you do not receive an error when loading the file, the recognizer does not properly register the the .yml file.

By changing how the training_data.yml file is generated is the key. In your training code change the
        recognizer.save() to recognizer.write().

I had this issue when trying to load the training data on my Raspberry Pi.

If any clarity is needed make sure to ask.

## This method caused model.yml to be incorrectly loaded in my facialRecognition class

`Ids , faces = getImageList(path)`
   `recognizer.train(faces,np.array(Ids))`
   `recognizer.save('model.yml')`

## Changing the following line solved the issue.

`recognizer.write('model.yml')`

Both methods generated the model.yml file as expected but

`recognizer.read('model.yml')`

only worked with write().

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. The error you received is telling you that you need to call the train method in the parent class of `LBPHFaceRecognizer` before you ask it to do any recognition. Refer to [the documentation here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d65/classcv_1_1face_1_1FaceRecognizer.html#ac8680c2aa9649ad3f55e27761165c0d6).

Answer (score 0):

After all, if the error still there, try to manually specify the full path of recognizer.write().

Example:

```
recognizer.write('/home/pi/Desktop/.../trainer/trainer.yml')
```

This worked for me.